# Using SQL Query to echo table

Tags: php, sql, debugging, html-table, echo

```
<?php
$product_list="";
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM products WHERE category LIKE'$category'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$tablerow='3';
$product_list.='<tr>';
   while($tablerow >= 0){
      $id=$row["id"];
      $name=$row["name"];
      $price=$row["price"];
      $date_added = strftime("%b %d, 20%y",strtotime($row["date_added"]));
      $discriptiontags = $row['category'];
      $discription = $row['subcategory'];
      $size = $row['details'];
      $qty= $row['inv'];
      $product_list.='<td><img src="inventory_images/'.$id.'.jpg" width="250" height="167"/><br/>$name</td>';
      $tablerow=$tablerow-1;
}
$product_list.='</tr>';
 }
}else{
$product_list = "no products in this category";
exit();
 }          
?>
```

so the thought behind this is; use the $_GET to grab a category tag for my database and use LIKE to find the row info and display each rows info in a single table cell from a table that is 3 columns across and dynamically adds additional rows.

here is the html from the spot it is supposed to be displayed

```
      <table width="760px" border="1" cellpadding="4">
      <?php echo $product_list ?>
      </table>
```

[link to page in question](http://glamourpawscollars.com/products.php?cat=green&tab=1)

I select the green category for testing because it has 3 items.

also for some reason the page does not display at all if the url variables are not set...????

the rest of the php on the page:

```
<?php 
///conect to mysql
///grab page variable
include "storescript/connect_to_mysql.php";
$category="";
$tab="-1";
if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
    $category=$_GET['cat'];
}
if(isset($_GET['tab'])){
    $tab=$_GET['tab'];
}
?>
```

Comment: I have to admin that I did not read the entire post but this `while($tablerow >= 0)` seems useless as mysql_fetch_array will fetch the results row by row.. and btw, based on the usage you could switch to mysql_fetch_assoc.. not to mention the big notice you can see on the man page advising developers to use mysqli or pdo

Comment: the while($tablerow >= 0) is used to have that inner while loop only run three times before resetting the $tablerow, and as said i am noob this is my first time trying to code php without a tutorial so I have no idea what mysqli or pdo is.

Comment: Why do you use LIKE? The way you use it has the same effect as when you used `category = '$category'`.

Comment: category contains text such as" red medium Christmas" so I was under the impression LIKE would scan the whole category text for one instance of the $category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `category LIKE '%red%'` to match categories like "red medium Christmas" and "alsored category" and so on. `category LIKE 'red'` only matches the category "red".

Refer to http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php to learn more about `LIKE`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah for some reason i was thinking because i seperated the words with spaces that they where separate text strings...:( anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use exit(); it's stop the script. So it never "echo" even "no products in this category".

If first code is included, use return; instead of exit(). But I can't see where you insert which code.

Comment: ive replaced the exit() with return; also removed it entirely with no change. it will not display, i also placed an additional <?php echo $product_list ?> outside of the table tags to see if it would show but it still will not.